# prototypes on objects/arrays and loops

Tags: javascript, prototype

Had a strange bug appear today. In our app, on one file, all the objects got a function attached, as if they were prototyped. We're not prototyping our arrays but I've worked on other stuff where the arrays and objects had prototypes and when you did a for(this in that) loop the prototypes would be included as items and we had to filter them. So, two part question:

1. If you prototype your arrays will the index increase by + # of prototypes? So if array(a,b,c) has array.prototype.function(), would it's index count be 3 or 4?
2. Should this be happening?

We're thinking one of the jquery plugins we have is being all evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "index count" I assume you mean `length` property. In which case, the answer to your first question is "no." The `length` property is tied to the highest numerical index of an array. So, for instance, if you have the following code, `arr.length` will be `4`:

```
var arr = [];
arr[3] = true;
arr.length; //is 4
```

However, you referred to for-in loops, which have strange behavior in this situation. If we perform a for-in on `arr` (from above), we get the following:

```
var output = "";
for (i in arr) { //Don't do this!
    output += i;
} 
output; //is "3" (not "0123" as you might expect)
```

As I mentioned, prototyped properties have no impact on the length:

```
Array.prototype.foo = true;
var arr = [];
arr[3] = true;
arr.length; //is 4
```

However, they do impact for-in loops (under normal circumstances):

```
var output = "";
for (i in arr) { //arr from the previous code block.
    output += i;
} 
output; //is "3foo" (or maybe "foo3", there's no guarantee form the spec either way)
```

There are a few ways to get around this. First of all, you should really never be using for-in on array objects because of this kind of nonsense. But if you MUST do it for some reason, you should always protect your for-in loop using a `hasOwnProperty()` filter, like so:

```
var output = "";
for (i in arr) { //arr from the previous code block
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        output += i;
    }
} 
output; //is "3"
```

Again, *there's no guarantee of ordering on for-in.* So if `arr` was `[1,1,1]`, you might get `output` as `"201"` (though it's unlikely).

Another option is to try and save yourself from others' bad coding by using a feature of ES5 (if present) to protect your prototyped properties on the object level by setting them to be non-enumerable. You would do that like this:

```
var foo = (function() { /* do something */ });
if(typeof Object.defineProperty === "function") { //If ES5
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "foo", {
        value: foo,
        enumerable: false //make it not enumerable
    });
} else { //For older browsers
    Array.prototype.foo = foo;
}

var arr = [], output = "";
arr[3] = true;

for(i in arr) { //Seriously, don't do this.
    output += i;
}
output; //is "3"
```

I cannot stress enough that doing a for-in over an Array is a **bad idea**. In fact, I would tend to avoid for-in under pretty much all circumstances because you never know if someone out there wants to be a jerk and will toss this into the middle of their code:

```
Object.prototype.ponies = "Ponies!";
```

Answer (score 2):

Although arrays are objects, and thus can have number of properties, ONLY integer properties count toward the `array` itself.

```
var a = [];
alert(a.length); // 0
a.foo = "Ha";
alert(a.length); // 0
a[1] = 10;
alert(a.length); // 1

Array.prototype.shuffle = function() { ... }
alert(a.length); // 1
```

Though it is not recommended to use `for ... in` to process arrays, some people still do.  `for ... in` would find both `foo` and `shuffle`.

Answer (score 1):

If you avoid using `for (var i in array)` to iterate your arrays and iterate them ONLY by numeric index from 0 to `array.length - 1`, then you will NOT have problems if someone adds something to the array prototype.  This is exactly why you should avoid using the `for/in` technique for iterating arrays.

Some safe ways to iterate arrays no matter how many properties or methods have been added to the array or the array prototype:

```
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    // access array[i] here
}

var i = 0, len = array.length;
while (i < len) {
    // access array[i] here
    i++;
}
```